# How to autotab after input of 1 or 2 decimal places in textbox vba?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I want to move focus to next textbox after entering a value with lets say one decimal place eg. "123.4", as well it should not move if the value entered is text eg. "abc.e". Is there any way?

Comment: What have you tried till now? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The focus is automatically moved to the next control when press Enter... What do you want the code doing in case of something else than a numeric value with one decimal? Should it refuze the input sending a relevant message, the focus back to the text box itself and let us say, select the inappropriate text?

Comment: Well I tried AutoTab property from property window, but it basically moves focus after maxlength is achieved.

Comment: What do you mean by "maxlength"? And I asked some other clarification questions... Are you able to answer them?

Comment: There is a property for TextBox in property box called "MaxLength" which restricts you from entering more characters than you specify.

Comment: What if the user wants to enter 123.45? Autotabbing out can be frustating. As far as `"abc.e"` is concerned, that can be handeled very easily... Do do you want to restrict to only 1 decimal place?

Comment: And to answer your another question, if other characters are typed then focus should stay where it is

Comment: What is the objective here? to allow only 2 decimal places?

Comment: I am using TextBox to enter quantity

Comment: The concern is not how many decimal places, it may vary from 1 to 5 as per requirement.

Comment: Yes but is Autotabbing the actual objective or allowing decimals only  is the objective?

Comment: See the answer that I posted.

Comment: What I want here is to avoid pressing Enter Key to move next TextBox, basically my input is like"12.5", "146.8", "2548.1", etc. So as soon as I press any number after decimal place the focus should move to next field. Hope that explains everything.

Comment: Then, test the code I posted. But it will jump to the control you want after you write first decimal... You cannot enter more then one decimal. If you set a specific limit, the code can be easily adapted to deal with that specific limit.

Comment: Sure, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the next code, please:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
 If Len(Me.TextBox1.Text) >= 3 Then
    If IsNumeric(Me.TextBox1.Text) And _
            Right(Me.TextBox1.Text, 3) Like "#.#" Then
       'controlX.SetFocus
       'Me.txtTest.SetFocus
    End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Using it together with the above event posted by @Siddharth Rout (not allowing other characters than numbers) should be the perfect solution for you, I think. In such a case, `IsNumeric(...)` check can be missing.

If you need to make it allowing two decimal, it is enough to replace "#.#" with "#.##" and make `Len(...) >= 4` and so on...

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: I already mentioned that in my answer... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your objective is not about AutoTabbing but restricting the inputs in the Textbox. If that is true then this may help.

You can restrict the keys pressed in the textbox using `KeyPress` event. The below code will allow **ONLY** numbers and decimal besides navigation.

Is this what you are trying? Doesn't need any reference to work

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyDelete, _
             vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
            If KeyAscii = 46 Then If InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, ".") Then KeyAscii = 0
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
            Beep
    End Select
End Sub
```

If you still want Autotabbing then that can also be handled here.

Comment: Nice! Voted it up. But the question was not clear enough...

Comment: Thanks for this code too, this code also helpful, it prevents user from entering characters other than numbers and decimal point

Comment: @NikhilBhor: I think you missed the last line...`If you still want Autotabbing then that can also be handled here.` Anyways... I can see that you have got what you wanted so all good :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can use `Regular Expressions`.

```
'needs reference to MS VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim spattern As String, sText As String
    Dim r As RegExp
    Dim bResult As Boolean
    
    If Len(TextBox1.Text) < 3 Then Exit Sub
    
    sText = TextBox1.Text
    'define pattern
    spattern = "\d{1,}" & Application.DecimalSeparator & "\d{1,2}"
    Set r = New RegExp
    With r
        .pattern = spattern
        bResult = .Test(sText)
    End With
    
    If bResult Then
        'move focus to the next control
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well I don't know much about regular expression

Comment: So, there's time to improve your knowledge ;) At this moment, you've got working example.